# Where to watch Free Live Streaming of Cricket World Cup 2015?

Tags: cricket-world-cup

The cricket worldcup 2015 is near. I searched for some free live streaming of the cricket world cup 2015 matches but most the web sites are either asking for subscription charges or are just spam. Does anyone know where can I watch cricket matches for free?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for links to sites which infringe copyright.

Comment: @PhilipKendall That and any [source requests](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are discouraged per the help center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you are from the Indian subcontinent & Star Sports is the official broadcaster in the region. All the World Cup 2015 matches will be live streamed on Star Sports official website for a very small & affordable & worthy subscription fee.

The reason the official stream is much better compared to the pirated streams is that on Star Sports stream you can watch the entire match as a replay if you miss the live event & shuffle between the timeline of the match. And all this in HD.

Edit : Just checked the subscription charge. Approx 2$ for the entire world cup.

This is not an advert. Just sharing my wonderful experience using the site